# How to set the text inside a <select> element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there any way to set a text in a `<select>`? For example:

```
$("select_list").val("Hello World");
$("select_list").text("Hello World");
$("select_list").html("Hello World");
```

None of these functions seems to work or set the text in my `<select>`. Help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide the HTML code?

Comment: Your question is not clear. You don't set the text inside a `select` element - you choose the option to be displayed. Do you instead mean that you want to change the text within a specific `option` element?

Comment: i mean i want to set a text to the <select> box much like how to place a text in an input text field. ex. $("text_box").text("hello world");

Comment: <select> box??? You means text field?

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to treat a select element like a ComboBox.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear enough! Any way try this, this will change first option.

```
$(".select_element option").text("Hello");
```

your HTML should be

```
<select class="select_element" >
   <option></option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

This way you can change the value of the selected option from the select list.

```js
$( "#selectList option:selected").text("Text");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="selectList">
  <option>ABC</option>
  <option>DEF</option>
  <option selected="selected">GHI</option>
</select>
```